# SSRS Rectangle auto growing

Tags: reporting-services, reportbuilder

I have textbox inside a table cell (this is the default configuration) and value in the text box's text is empty and it used purely as a toggle button for a child grouping. In the design image below I have colour coded for emphasis the 6 grouping levels in red (one pink). When I run it is all fine there is a single row of data, I click the toggle and the child group shows as this is the way I have set it up. I wanted to add something else to the cell that contained the toggle (i.e. the pink cell) so I changed my textbox to a rectangle and I added first in a sense the original textbox (placed in the top left hand corner of the rectangle) and ran the report and now the rectangle's height has grown to 2 rows at run time as supposed to one row (height of the textbox) at design time - why? Is there a way to prevent this?

NB: the run time screen shot is me changing the height and width of the rectangle to an arbitrary size greater than the width and height of the textbox. So when the report is run the width stays the same the height doubles.

**Design Time**

With 6 textboxes (NB: each box represents a different hierarchical (drill down) level)
[image: Design Time]

After I change the 2nd textbox (counting right to left) to Rectangle (arbitrary height and width) + Textbox

[image]

**Run Time**

(NB: height of rectangle doubles in size at runtime compared to design time)
[image]

Comment: Can you add images of the design and runtime layouts of the rectangle. Are you overlapping control in the rectangle as SSRS doesn't like this and will set each one on a new row is they do not fit side by side

Comment: When you say overlap what do you mean? I have one textbox inside a rectangle what is there to overlap. I have said above the height of the rectangle is the height of the textbox (doesn't make any difference if I add one more pixel to the height of the rectangle or take one off the textbox) and it is implied the width of the rectangle is greater than the width of the textbox as I have also said I was attempting to add something else but I haven't yet and I was testing it before I get to that step. If I have time later I put screen shots if u deem necessary.

Comment: I don't think you can stop a rectangle from growing in height. Howver, the issue you're having is probably related to the rectangle not being able grow horizontally and maybe forcing a new line as there is no more space horizontally. So, first make sure that the rectangle has the correct width. If that didn't cause the problem then perhaps padding and margins might the reason.

Comment: Grow horizontally!? The text is empty and the toggle does not cause the textbox to grow. As you can see from the screen shot. There is plenty of room and it does not matter what the initial width and height of the rectangle is at design time but at runtime the width stays the same however the height always doubles.

Comment: That screenshot doesn't really help, there is nothing on it... could you perhaps add a screenshot of the layout at design time? Until I get a better idea of what exactly you're doing, I can't really give any well-founded advice, I still believe the problem might be caused by the fact that a rectangle is **unable** to grow horizontally causing a new line when the length of the width gets exceeded. Make sure that there is enough horizontal space in both the rectangle and table column

Comment: I added the design time image if it helps.

Comment: I'm afraid it's still unclear to me what exactly is going on your report. Right now I still can't tell what exactly is going, let alone what could be the cause of your problem.  You should explain more about what exactly you're creating and give a detailed description of the wanted result.Perhaps then I'll be able to help solve your issue or come up with a different approach.

Comment: I do not want the rectangle to grow vertically, there is nothing more to it than that. Please re-read the question.

Comment: And another point you made early "... rectangle is **unable** to grow horizontally causing a new line when the length of the width gets exceeded ...", which is irrelevant, besides the fact there is plenty of room horizontally, as the height **doubles** which is different to "a new line".

Comment: I believe it is you who is not reading my comments correctly. You can not stop a rectangle from growing vertically. From what you've shared so far it's impossible to tell what exactly is causing it to grow. A possibility was that there wasn't enough space horizontally but if you say that this is not the case, I believe you but there must be something else causing the rectangle to have the current behavior.Until you can find out what exactly is the source of your issue, you won't be able to limit the height of the rectangle.

Comment: Still mystified and it is definitely not a horizontal width issue as it does not matter how wide I make the column, I have other reports using rectangles that have a lot more other controls in them other than just a single text box and the rectangle resizes to its contents. The only differential is the fact I am using the textbox as a toggle so I am not sure if this has a bearing or if there is a rendering bug in the report builder tool as I cannot see I am doing anything obviously wrong. I will have to experiment further by say removing the toggle and see if it makes a difference. Stay tuned.